# Is there a $\mathrm{p}^0$ particle?

Tags: particle-physics, interactions, protons, textbook-erratum

In the following equation of a reaction

$$\mathrm{p}^0 + \mathrm{n} \to \mathrm{K}^+ + \Sigma^-$$

What is the quark composition of the $\mathrm{p}^0$ particle? Or is it supposed to be $\rho^0$?

[image: Photo from textbook]

For me it certainly looks more like $\mathrm p$, not $\mathrm \rho$.

(Source: K. A. Tsokos, *Physics for the IB Diploma*, Sixth Edition, Cambridge University Press)

Comment: In any case, the [particle data group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/) is your friend. Their review (and more conveniently the data booklet) have compositions of the know particles. And I'll spare you a little misery by noting that a rho is a "light, unflavored meson".

Comment: I am sure. Although your suggestion of a misrepresentation is correct. I suggest to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it (or suggest me to delete the question if it is appropriate here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a typo for
$$ \rm \rho^0 + n \to K^+ + \Sigma^- $$
where $\rho^0$ is the uncharged member of the isospin triplet with mass 770 MeV.
According to the [particle data group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/), the quark content of the light, unflavored mesons with isospin $I=1$ is $u\bar d, (u\bar u - d\bar d)/\sqrt2, d\bar u$.

You can tell that your "$p$" must be a meson, not a baryon, because both sides of the reaction must have the same baryon number, and the baryon number on the right side is $+1$.

Commenters on [a duplicate question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258689/44126) point out that it may also by a typo for $\pi^0$, if the printer's software produces the character "π" using the same code point as "p" but in some other typeface.  Like the $\rho$, the $\pi$ also has zero baryon number and unit isospin; however the pion is spinless while the rho is a spin-one "vector" meson.