# Mystery $p^0$ particle

Tags: particle-physics, interactions

Some exercises in my physics book mention a particle denoted $p^0$, but I can't seem to find any information about this particle, neither in my book nor on the web. I've been able to deduce from the exercises that it's not a baryon (because $p+n\rightarrow p+p^0$ apparently violates conservation of baryon number), but I haven't got much closer than that.

Some examples:

- $\pi^+ \rightarrow p^0 + e^+ + v_e$
- $p^0 + n \rightarrow K^0 + \Sigma^-$

Comment: It's very very likely meant to be a $\pi^0$.

Comment: This can happen when a manuscript is prepared using a "Symbol" font for (some of) the Greek letters.  In most such fonts, $\pi$ is created by typing "p" and then switching the font.  If the manuscript is then transferred to a computer that doesn't have that particular font installed, it reverts to the "p".

Comment: Which physics book?

Comment: the second relation does not conserve charge as written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo in the book `K. A. Tsokos, Physics for the IB Diploma, Sixth Edition, Cambridge University Press`.

The symbol is supposed to be $\mathrm \rho$, not $\mathrm p$.

Source: [Is there a $\mathrm{p}^0$ particle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211253/is-there-a-mathrmp0-particle)